# SQLITE ERROR while creating and inserting

Tags: android, sqlite

Somebody help, I dont know what is wrong with this code, looks fine to me...
This is my code sqlite

```
package com.ilab.klr3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class SQLiteDbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DB_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DB_NAME="klr";
    public static final String CHAPTER_NUMBER="chapter_number";
    public static final String CHAPTER_NAME="chapter_name";
    public static final String CHAPTER_TITLE="chapter_title";
    public static final String PART_DESC="part_description";
    public static final String PART_NUMBER="part_number";
    public static final String PART_TITLE="part_title";
    public static final String ARTICLE_ID="article_id";
    public static final String ARTICLE_CONTENT="article_content";
    public static final String ARTICLE_NUMBER="article_numer";

    public SQLiteDbhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_chapters=String.format("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,%s TEXT, " +
                "%s TEXT, %s TEXT);",KLRConstants.TABLE_CHAPTER,KLRConstants.CHAPTER_ID, CHAPTER_NUMBER,CHAPTER_NAME,CHAPTER_TITLE);
        String create_parts=String.format("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,%s TEXT, " +
                "%s TEXT, %s TEXT);",KLRConstants.TABLE_PARTS,KLRConstants.PART_ID,PART_DESC,PART_NUMBER,PART_TITLE);
        String create_articles=String.format("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,%s TEXT, " +
                "%s TEXT, %s TEXT);",KLRConstants.TABLE_ARTICLES,KLRConstants.ARTICLE_ID,ARTICLE_ID,ARTICLE_CONTENT,ARTICLE_NUMBER);
        db.execSQL(create_articles);
        db.execSQL(create_chapters);
        db.execSQL(create_parts);
        (new InsertSampleData(db)).execute();
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
    class InsertSampleData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        SQLiteDatabase database=null;
        public InsertSampleData(SQLiteDatabase database){
            this.database=database;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Chapter chapter1 = new Chapter("I","CHAPTER ONE","SOVEREIGNTY OF THE PEOPLE AND SUPREMACY OF THIS CONSTITUTION");
            Chapter chapter2 = new Chapter("II","CHAPTER TWO","THE REPUBLIC"); 
            Chapter chapter3 = new Chapter("III","CHAPTER THREE","CITIZENSHIP"); 
            Chapter chapter4 = new Chapter("IV","CHAPTER FOUR","BILL OF RIGHTS"); 
            Chapter chapter5 = new Chapter("V","CHAPTER FIVE","LAND AND ENVIRONMENT"); 
            Chapter chapter6 = new Chapter("VI","CHAPTER SIX","LEADERSHIP AND INTEGRITY"); 

            KLRDBAdapter klradapter=new KLRDBAdapter(database);
            klradapter.inserChapter(chapter1);
            klradapter.inserChapter(chapter2);
            klradapter.inserChapter(chapter3);
            klradapter.inserChapter(chapter4);
            klradapter.inserChapter(chapter5);
            klradapter.inserChapter(chapter6);

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
03-26 00:40:11.170: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(12343): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table chapter has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied, db=/data/data/com.ilab.klr3/databases/klr
03-26 00:40:11.185: E/KLRDBAdapter(12343): Could not create or Open the database
03-26 00:40:11.220: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(12343): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table chapter has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied,
```

I am trying to create database as well as insert but I get the error above. I dont understand this since i have done this a number of times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very clear from your code.  You are creating table `chapter` with four columns but are specifying only 3 values on the insert.

Your `create table` is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chapters (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    chapter_number TEXT,
    chapter_name TEXT,
    chapter_title TEXT);
```

And your insert (which is not shown but seems to be from the error) is

```
INSERT INTO chapters VALUES (
    'I',
    'CHAPTER ONE',
    'SOVEREIGNTY OF THE PEOPLE AND SUPREMACY OF THIS CONSTITUTION');
```

Because your `_id` is `autoincrement`, you don't need to specify it - but now because you are not specifying all the columns, you need to explicitly specify which columns you are inserting, therefore your `insert` statement should be:

```
INSERT INTO chapters 
    (chapter_number, chapter_name, chapter_title)
VALUES (
    'I',
    'CHAPTER ONE',
    'SOVEREIGNTY OF THE PEOPLE AND SUPREMACY OF THIS CONSTITUTION');
```